# How to shift ARGV after OptionParser?

Tags: ruby, optionparser

I'm extending a class, which uses [OptionParser](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/OptionParser.html) to parse command-line options.

I'd like my class to process the arguments *remaining after* the last option. Is there some equivalent in Ruby to the `optind` available to the callers of `getopt(3)` in C?

Some way of determining, how many options were found in `ARGV` -- so I can `shift` by that many to skip the *options* and process only the *arguments*?

I have access to the `opt_parser` object itself, for example. Can I, perhaps, figure out from it, how many pieces of my `ARGV` it consumed?

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". Your question needs to define the problem better. Show us in code, along with an example invocation, what your output should be.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your question, can you add a minimal example to show your problem.

If I run this minimal example with the options `-v test`:

```
require 'optparse'

#Anlegen des Parsers
opts = OptionParser.new()
opts.on("-v", "--[no-]verbose", "Run verbosely") { |v|
  puts "->Verbose is #{v.inspect}"
}

opts.parse!

puts "Remaining ARGV: %s" % ARGV.inspect
```

then I get the result

```
->Verbose is true
Remaining ARGV: ["test"]
```

After you parse the options, ARGV contains the remaining arguments.

Comment: You very are probably right -- apparently, the underlying class I'm using -- `Sensu::Plugin::Check::CLI -- makes a copy of `ARGV` before passing it OptionParser. But, I found, I can get the processed list (with options removed) as `argv` (lower case), so I'm fine... Wish, I could delete the question, but I can't...

Comment: Isn't there a 'delete'-option under the badges? Normally it is possible for the questioner to delete his own question.

Comment: When I posted that comment, the deletion was not working because the question is already answered. Now, instead of prohibiting the deletion outright, the site warns, that repeatedly deleting answered questions will make me a bad person. Something must've changed in this short time...